# Doctrine 2 how to count the Users that partecipate to an Event? (so a COUNT on GROUP BY)

Tags: doctrine-orm, group-by

I have 3 tables in my DB:

- user (_id, name)
- event (_id, name, ...)
- events_partecipants(user_id, event_id)

I have two Doctrine entities which maps those tables and their relations and everything works (eg. I'm able to get all the partecipants for a specific event).

Now, I want to retrieve the number of events each user joined to. Using pure SQL the query will be:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count
FROM events_partecipants
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

As result, I want to retrieve also the name of each user, so I can send back into my JSON information about each user with the name, and not the ID.
If I want to use Doctrine how this can be achieved? I cannot find a smart way to do that.